# volume button control on every pages

Tags: javascript, audio, controls, transition

i' m trying to make an audio button for turn on or turn off the sound on my website, my problem is when i go on an other page of my website the volume come back... and i have song on every pages, how can i fix it ? 
there is my code:

```js
var volume = document.getElementById('song');

document.getElementById('mute').addEventListener('click', function (e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    volume.muted = !volume.muted;
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```html
<audio autoplay loop id="song">
   <source src="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a" />
</audio>


<div id="mute">
    <a href="#"><button>volume</button></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You would need to use something like a cookie, which you read on the page loading and prevent the music from playing. Unless your site is a single page javascript app, I think this is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) or use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). You will need to set the data when the button is clicked, retrieve it on page load, and mute accordingly.